# How many days between two dates?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have two dates returned from an SQL query, how can I calculate the number of days they cover?

IE:

```
$date1 = '2013-08-08';
$date2 = '2013-08-12';
$days = ???;
```

Comment: Convert the strings to [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects, and use the [diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method as shown in Example #1 on the diff() method page of the PHP documentation

Comment: Valid question, with a good answer I can use in the future. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A purely php solution:

```
$date1= new DateTime("2013-08-08");
$date2 = new DateTime("2013-08-12");

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

echo $diff->format("%a days ago");
```

Answer (score 5):

As an option you can return date difference right from your sql query along with other data using `DATEDIFF()`

```sql
SELECT date1, 
       date2, 
       DATEDIFF(date2, date1) date_diff
  FROM ...
```

Sample output:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| date1      | date2      | date_diff |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2013-08-08 | 2013-08-12 |         4 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5a493/1)** demo